# How do I install Realtek rtl8821ce driver on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, 18.10, realtek-wireless

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on a new Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IKB laptop, but the Wi-Fi is not supported.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: CAUTION: We have dueling duplicates here. For kernel versions 4.15 and newer, the answer I wrote that incolved downloading a zip file is likely to not compile properly. If you are running Ubuntu 18.10, then the other duplicate involving the git repository of tomaspinho *will* compile. Confirm your kernel version with the terminal command: `uname -r`